# terraform helm release timeout while waiting for condition

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using terraform to provision some resources in azure and I can't seem to get helm to install nginx-ingress because it timeouts waiting for condition

> - helm_release.nginx_ingress: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - helm_release.nginx_ingress: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = release nginx-ingress failed: timed out waiting for the condition
>
> Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
>   Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with any
>   resources that successfully completed. Please address the error above
>   and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure. main.tf

```
data "azurerm_public_ip" "nginx_ingress" {
    name                = "xxxx-public-ip"
    resource_group_name = "xxxx-public-ip"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "xxxx_RG" {
  name     = "${var.name_prefix}"
  location = "${var.location}"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
    name                    = "${var.name_prefix}-aks"
    kubernetes_version      = "${var.kubernetes_version}"
    location                = "${azurerm_resource_group.xxxx_RG.location}"
    resource_group_name     = "${azurerm_resource_group.xxxx_RG.name}"
    dns_prefix              = "AKS-${var.dns_prefix}"

    agent_pool_profile {
        name                = "${var.node_pool_name}"
        count               = "${var.node_pool_size}"
        vm_size             = "${var.node_pool_vmsize}"
        os_type             = "${var.node_pool_os}"
        os_disk_size_gb     = 30
    }

    service_principal {
        client_id           = "${var.client_id}"
        client_secret       = "${var.client_secret}"
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "${var.env_tag}"
    }
}

provider "helm" {
  install_tiller = true

  kubernetes {
    host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.host}"
    client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  }
}

# Add Kubernetes Stable Helm charts repo
resource "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url  = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
}

# Install Nginx Ingress using Helm Chart
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress"
  repository = "${helm_repository.stable.metadata.0.name}"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress"
  wait       = "true"

  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = "false"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = "${data.azurerm_public_ip.nginx_ingress.ip_address}"
  }
}
```

Then deploying my application with this

```
provider "kubernetes" {
    host                    = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.host}"
    username                = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.username}"
    password                = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.password}"
    client_certificate      = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key              = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate  = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "flask_api_deployment" {
    metadata {
        name = "flask-api-deployment"
    }

    spec {
        replicas = 1
        selector {
            match_labels {
                component = "api"
            }
        }

        template {
            metadata {
                labels = {
                    component = "api"
                }
            }

            spec {
                container {
                    image = "xxxx.azurecr.io/sampleflask:0.1.0"
                    name = "flask-api"
                    port {
                        container_port = 5000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "flask_api_ingress_service" {
    metadata {
        name = "flask-api-ingress-service"
    }

    spec {
        backend {
            service_name = "flask-api-cluster-ip-service"
            service_port = 5000
        }
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "flask_api_cluster_ip-service" {
    metadata {
        name = "flask-api-cluster-ip-service"
    }

    spec {
        selector {
            component = "api"
        }

        port {
            port = 5000
            target_port = 5000
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what condition its waiting for. I can set the timeout larger but that doesn't seem to help. I can also set wait = false in the helm release but then no resources seem to get provisioned.

EDIT: From some testing I've done I see there is an issue when specifying the loadbalancerIP in the helm release. If I comment that out it completes just fine.

EDIT: From more testing I've found that the load balancer that is created is failing to be created. controller: user supplied IP Address 52.xxx.x.xx was not found in resource group MC_xxxxxxxx

So I guess the question is how do I allow specifying an IP from a different resource group?

Comment: I suspect its waiting for the service to finish setting things up and fails to do so, can you confirm service is provisioned and public ip is available?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to re-run `terraform apply?`

Comment: Yeah rerunning will cause the same error.

Comment: confirmed that the ingress service is running and that the public ip is available. The public ip is not provisioned by terraform and is in a different resource group - don't know if that matters here or not.

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving RBAC off? You’re better off enabling it.

Comment: using alessandro's code from below I actually get a somewhat more useful error - helm_release.nginx_ingress: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Running'

Comment: Any update for the question? Does it work for you? Please let me know if you have any more question.

Comment: Don't keep silent. Please let me know it's helpful or not!

Comment: not helpful at all sorry. I know how to install nginx ingress in AKS but what I can't do is to use a public ip from a different resource group

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can take a look at the steps you missed. Additionally, don't change the question to a new one again.

Comment: Still the same issue. I could use load balancer service instead of ingress and ip in a different resource group would work. But I need ingress here

Comment: Yes, it's also for the ingress. You should set the annotations for service in the "helm_release" set block. Actually, the ingress also uses the service. By the way, please @ me if you send the comment for me.

Comment: @CharlesXu I've done this in the helm release as well, still no luck set {
    name = "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group"
    value = "xxxx"
  }

Comment: The name format is wrong. Take a look at [the static public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip#create-an-ingress-controller). It should be `controller.service."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group"` and value is the group name that the public IP in.

Comment: @CharlesXu I can try that but I'll need to figure out how to set that in terraform helm release. It doesn't like that syntax.

Comment: @CharlesXu setting name  = "controller.service.\"service\\kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group\"" doesn't seem to help. Still getting the error.

Comment: If you use the helm command, it works. So it's the solution. But you need to know how the set it in the terraform.

Comment: I update the answer and show you the screenshot of the result. You can take a look.

Comment: @CharlesXu - I read through that helm stuff and you're right it definately is the solution. Getting that to work with terraform was a nightmare. But this solution works now. It didn't work last night but I ran it again this morning and it completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install the nginx-ingress in AKS cluster through helm in Terraform, here I show one way that available here. In this way, you need to install the helm in the machine which you want to run the terraform script. And then you also need to configure the helm to your AKS cluster. The steps in [Configure the helm to AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-helm#create-a-service-account). You can check if the helm configured to AKS through installing something to the AKS.

When everything is ready. You just need to set the helm provider and use the resource `helm_release`. The Terraform script to install the nginx-ingress shows here:

```
provider "helm" {
  version = "~> 0.9"
}

resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
    name = "application1"
    chart = "stable/nginx-ingress"
    version = "1.10.2"
    namespace = "ingress-basic"

    set {
        name = "controller.replicaCount"
        value = "1"
    }

    ...

}
```

The process shows here:

[image]

This is just to install the nginx-ingress through helm in Terraform. If you want to create resources of the kubernetes. You can use the kubernetes in Terraform.

**Update**:

OK, to use a static public IP in another resource group for your ingress, you need to do two more steps.

1. The service principal used by the AKS cluster must have delegated permissions to the other resource group which the public IP in. The permission should be "Network Contributor" at least.
2. Set the ingress service annotations with the value of the resource group which the public IP in.

The annotation in the yaml file would like this:

```
annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup
```

For more details, see [Use a static IP address outside of the node resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#use-a-static-ip-address-outside-of-the-node-resource-group).

**Update1:**

The code in the "helm_release":

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
    name = "application1223"
    chart = "stable/nginx-ingress"
        version = "1.10.2"
    namespace = "ingress-basic"

    set {
        name = "controller.replicaCount"
        value = "1"
    }

    set {
      name = "controller.service.annotations.\"service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group\""
      value = "v-chaxu-xxxx"
    }

    set {
      name = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
      value = "13.68.175.40"
    }

}
```

When it deploys successfully, the ingress service shows like this:

[image]

The info of the public IP which is in another resource group:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue (helm_release getting timed out). On further investigation, I found out that the Public IP was not getting assigned to the load balancer (kubectl describe svc nginx-ingress -n ingress-basic) because of incorrect RBAC permissions.

I was using Azure AKS Managed Identity feature by which Azure automatically creates a managed identity service principal which has only very limited permission (readonly permission to Managed Cluster resource group which is automatically created by AKS). My Pubic IP is in another resource group and load balancer was in managed resource group by AKS cluster.

Finally I was able to fix the issue by using 'Service Principal' option instead of managed identity in AKS cluster with 'contributor' access to subscription for the service principal.

So if any one is facing some issue with Managed Identity, please try using Service Principal with contributor access to the subscription, and that will fix the issue

Comment: I upvoted because IMO this answers the original question most directly. The general issue that people seem to be having is that the helm provider requires a public IP to be assigned to the ingress controller in order to finish successfully.

Answer (score 3):

It’s best practise to enable RBAC in your cluster. An example how to do it with Terraform and subsequently install Helm is:

```
…
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
…

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = "true"
  }

}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.host}"
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}

resource "kubernetes_service_account" "tiller_sa" {
  metadata {
    name      = "tiller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "tiller_sa_cluster_admin_rb" {
  metadata {
    name = "tiller-cluster-role"
  }
  role_ref {
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "cluster-admin"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = "${kubernetes_service_account.tiller_sa.metadata.0.name}"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    api_group = ""
  }
}

# helm provider
provider "helm" {
  debug           = true
  namespace       = "kube-system"
  service_account = "tiller"
  install_tiller  = "true"
  tiller_image    = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v${var.TILLER_VER}"
  kubernetes {
    host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.host}"
    client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  }
}

data "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url  = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
}

resource "helm_release" "datadog" {
  name       = "datadog"
  namespace  = "datadog"
  repository = "${data.helm_repository.stable.metadata.0.name}"
  chart      = "stable/datadog"

  set {
    name  = "datadog.apiKey"
    value = "${var.datadog_apikey}"
  }

}
```

Comment: cool, so that helps get this aligned with best practices more but I still get the timeout issue that I was writing about.

Comment: actually this gives me a better error. I now get helm_release.nginx_ingress: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Running'

Comment: means the chart failed to install and timed out. Do you see pods in running state?

Comment: I see my pods running, when I get pods for that kube-system namespace I see the following: coredns-7fbf4847b6-6mcx8, coredns-7fbf4847b6-fxfxs, coredns-autoscaler-657d77ffbf-78rww, kube-proxy-79v7w, kube-proxy-dgrsk                       , kubernetes-dashboard-6f697bd9f5-76x8n, metrics-server-58699455bc-pf6lq, tiller-deploy-8485766469-hbqmw, tunnelfront-bb9b87486-6rtm8. All these pods are running. I'm not sure what other pods I'd be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the helm deployment (I was deploying traefik) timed out because the the **service** had `LoadBalance` type and trying to obtain an external ip, which isn't provided by MiniKube. As a workaround, I just manually editted the service type and changed to `NodePor`t and the deployment completed successfully immediately.

Answer (score 0):

From what I expirienced, a very common scenario for `timeout while waiting for condition` is the fact that **one of the resources** which are part of the Helm chart was **failing to be properly installed**.

In the more explicit cases, when a ServiceAccount, Role, atc' or even a CRD were failing to be installed - in those cases you'll probably get a clear error.

**The less clear use cases are for example** a deployment/statefulset/DaemonSet/etc' that was properly installed but the **pods are stuck on pending** for some reason (resources, taints, etc') **or crashing**.